# NavigationLink pushes twice, then pops once

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I have a login screen on which I programmatically push to the next screen using a hidden `NavigationLink` tied to a state variable. The push works, but it seems to push twice and pop once, as you can see on this screen recording:

[image]

This is my view hierarchy:

```
App
   NavigationView
      LaunchView
         LoginView
            HomeView
```

`App`:

```swift
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationView {
            LaunchView()
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .environmentObject(cache)
    }
}
```

`LaunchView`:

```swift
struct LaunchView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var cache: API.Cache
    @State private var shouldPush = API.shared.accessToken == nil
    
    func getUser() {
        [API call to get user, if already logged in](completion: { user in
            if let user = user {
                // in our example, this is NOT called
                // thus `cache.user.hasData` remains `false`
                cache.user = user
            }
            shouldPush = true
        }
    }
    
    private var destinationView: AnyView {
        cache.user.hasData
            ? AnyView(HomeView())
            : AnyView(LoginView())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if API.shared.accessToken != nil {
            getUser()
        }
        
        return VStack {
            ActivityIndicator(style: .medium)
            NavigationLink(destination: destinationView, isActive: self.$shouldPush) {
                EmptyView()
            }.hidden()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

This is a cleaned version of my `LoginView`:

```swift
struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var cache: API.Cache
    @State private var shouldPushToHome = false
   
    func login() {
        [API call to get user](completion: { user in
            self.cache.user = user
            self.shouldPushToHome = true
        })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                // labels
                // textfields
                // ...
                PrimaryButton(title: "Anmelden", action: login)
                NavigationLink(destination: HomeView(), isActive: self.$shouldPushToHome) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.hidden()
            }
            // label
            // signup button
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

The `LoginView` itself is child of a `NavigationView`.

The `HomeView` is really simple:

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var cache: API.Cache

    var body: some View {
        let user = cache.user
        
        return Text("Hello, \(user.contactFirstname ?? "") \(user.contactLastname ?? "")!")
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)

    }
}
```

What's going wrong here?

---

#### Update:

I've realized that the issue does *not* occur, when I replace `LaunchView()` in `App` with `LoginView()` directly. Not sure how this is related...

---

#### Update 2:

As Tushar pointed out below, replacing `destination: destinationView` with `destination: LoginView()` fixes the problem – but obviously lacks required functionality.
So I played around with that and now understand what's going on:

1. `LaunchView` is rendered
2. `LaunchView` finds there's no user data yet, so pushes to `LoginView`
3. upon user interaction, `LoginView` pushes to `HomeView`
4. at this point, the `NavigationLink` inside **`LaunchView`** is called *again* (idk why but a breakpoint showed this), and since there *is* user data now, it renders the `HomeView` instead of the `LoginView`.

That's why we see only one push animation, and the `LoginView` becoming the `HomeView` w/o any push animation, b/c it's *replaced*, essentially.

So now the objective is preventing `LaunchView`'s `NavigationLink` to re-render its destination view.

Comment: Can you try to hard code destination to LoginView() in your LaunchView to see what happens?

Comment: @TusharSharma that does fix the issue, indeed. So how else do I achieve my same logic?

Comment: I guess the problem is with the API calling, and how they update your model state, and views that are observing your model to perform refresh. You need to check that more carefully. If I test your code in most simple way, without depending on “Cache class" and "access token” value, and just use single @State property to toggle state, everything works perfect.

Comment: @TusharSharma thanks for the hint. I played around a little and have shared my findings above in *Update 2*.

Comment: from what I understand Your “cache” is  @EnvironmentObject property, so soon as any property value is changed for that model, all views marked with  EnvironmentObject will re-render there body.

Comment: Ohhh right, so `getUser()` is called every time the `cache.user` changes, right? Then the result of that triggers the repeated push via `NavigationLink`, which causes the issue.

Comment: yes, you got it right.

Comment: @TusharSharma thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I found a solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve the issue thanks to [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7460927/tushar-sharma)'s help [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516233/navigationlink-pushes-twice-then-pops-once#comment119337808_67516233).

#### Problem

The main problem lies in the fact I didn't understand how the environment object triggers re-renders. Here's what was going on:

1. `LaunchView` has the environment object `cache`, which is changed in `LoginView`, when we set `cache.user = user`.
2. That triggers the `LaunchView` to re-render its body.
3. since the access token is *not* `nil` after login, on each re-render, the user would be fetched from the API via `getUser()`.
4. disregarding the fact whether that api call yields a valid user, `shouldPush` is set to `true`
5. `LaunchView`'s body is rendered again and the `destinationView` is computed again
6. since now the user *does* have data, the computed view becomes `HomeView`
   This is why we see the `LoginView` becoming the `HomeView` w/o any push – it's being replaced.
7. at the same time, the `LoginView` pushes to `HomeView`, but since that view is already presented, it pops back to its first instance

#### Solution

To fix this, we need to make the property *not* computed, so that it only changes when we want it to. To do so, we can make it a state-managed variable and set it manually in the response of the `getUser` api call:

Excerpt from `LaunchView`:

```
// default value is `LoginView`, we could also
// set that in the guard statement in `getUser`
@State private var destinationView = AnyView(LoginView())

func getUser() {
    // only fetch if we have an access token
    guard API.shared.accessToken != nil else {
        return
    }
    API.shared.request(User.self, for: .user(action: .get)) { user, _, _ in
        cache.user = user ?? cache.user
        shouldPush = true
        // manually assign the destination view based on the api response
        destinationView = cache.user.hasData
            ? AnyView(HomeView())
            : AnyView(LoginView())
    }
}
    
var body: some View {
    // only fetch if user hasn't been fetched
    if cache.user.hasData.not {
        getUser()
    }

    return [all the views]
}
```